# Use rel=canonical or 301 redirect

Tags: 301-redirect, canonical-url

On my site both of these return the same content:

- `http://example.com/tags/sky`
- `http://example.com/tags/sky/page1`

Using `rel=canonical` on `page1` increases the coding complexity a bit, so can I do a (htaccess) 301 redirect

`http://example.com/tags/sky/page1` to `http://example.com/tags/sky`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer **Yes**.

The difference between the two as clearly pointed by [this article](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2288690/how-and-when-to-use-301-redirects-vs-canonical):

> **301** – Hey, Search Engines: My page is no longer here, and has permanently moved to a new page. Please remove it from your index and
>   pass credit to the new page.
>
> **Canonical** – Hey, (most) Search Engines: I have multiple versions of this page (or content), please only index this version. I'll keep
>   the others available for people to see, but don't include them in your
>   index and please pass credit to my preferred page.
>
> Regarding the amount of PageRank or link juice that would be lost from
>   canonical redirects, Cutts has also said "there's really not a whole
>   lot of difference" between the 301 and the canonical. This means the
>   301 and the canonical will lose "just a tiny little bit, not very much
>   at all" of credit from the referring page.

In either case (301 or Canonical) between 90-99% of link juice (ranking power) is passed to the redirected page.

At [SEO advice: url canonicalization](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/) Matt Cutts says that

> Suppose you want your default url to be http://www.example.com/ . You can make your webserver so that if someone requests http://example.com/, it does a 301 (permanent) redirect to http://www.example.com/ . That helps Google know which url you prefer to be canonical. Adding a 301 redirect can be an especially good idea if your site changes often (e.g. dynamic content, a blog, etc.).

[An article on juice and PR](https://www.seoblog.com/2014/06/link-juice-lost-301-redirect/)

Comment: Can you cite where you got `Between 90-99% of link juice` from? or did you just make that up for example purposes? a tiny bit isn't between 1-9%. Changing from canonical to 301 is not going to make any difference, in fact you won't even notice any difference, that is how much a tiny bit is... Structure your site for users, not search engines... rest comes naturally.

Comment: @SimonHayter the info was from [moz.com](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) I agree with you that website is for users but there's no harm if you take precautions..

Answer (score 1):

Without 301 redirects, two same pages could be considered like a duplicate for some search engine (there is a life out of google search engine). On the other hand, if you create 301 redirects, any search engines will understand the target page.

Still canonical is useful because sometimes bots & scripts add variables like: myvar=blabla at the end of the url. I think about the case when your page can be displayed with the same content from a different url with a variable at the end and you are not aware of it. Canonical ensures that any bots will understand the real url.

**Consequently, i think both 301 redirects and canonical are important because they are different (see answer from Rishi)**

Nevertheless, 301 redirect is better because it is more widely recognized according to Matt Cutts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW5UL3lzBOA

Answer (score 0):

The actual concept of Canonical Tags is for Search Engine not for user. 301 Redirect is for Bots and Humans (Users). 
Put Canonical to these pages

> `http://example.com/tags/sky/page1`

not redirect them. Because If you redirect them so User will not access further pages of these SKY tags.